StackOverflowError in Spark DataFrame due to too many filter expressions while filtering on specific partitions
I am working on a Spark (Scala) application where I need to filter out specific partitions (nested): region_name/audit_submission_date_hr_min. region_name is the top level partition. audit_submission_date_hr_min is the nested partition created every 15 mins. So I apply a series of filter expressions (around 3000 filter on DataFrame) on a large DataFrame.
Intent is to only process the partitions that have been not processed!
However, I am encountering a java.lang.StackOverflowError when executing the job.
1st-level partition:

2nd-level partition:

Code example -
val df = inputDf.filter(((region_name = emea) AND (audit_submission_date_hr_min = 2024-10-15-00-54-00)) OR ((region_name = africa) AND (audit_submission_date_hr_min = 2024-10-08-23-14-00)))
like ((region_name = emea) AND (audit_submission_date_hr_min = 2024-10-15-00-54-00)) OR ((region_name = africa) AND (audit_submission_date_hr_min = 2024-10-08-23-14-00)) 
        OR ((region_name = africa) AND (audit_submission_date_hr_min = 2024-10-08-04-29-00))) OR ((region_name = africa) AND (audit_submission_date_hr_min = 2024-10-08-17-14-00)))
        OR ((region_name = africa) AND (audit_submission_date_hr_min = 2024-10-13-17-14-00))) OR ((region_name = africa) AND (audit_submission_date_hr_min = 2024-10-14-15-44-00)))
        .
        . its 3000+ filter will be applied on 1 dataframe.
        .
        OR ((region_name = africa) AND (audit_submission_date_hr_min = 2024-10-13-17-14-00))) OR ((region_name = africa) AND (audit_submission_date_hr_min = 2024-10-14-15-44-00)))

Error
2024-10-16 20:25:28,899 ERROR ApplicationMaster [Driver]: User class threw exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate.genericBuilder(GenericTraversableTemplate.scala:72)
    ...
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.references(Expression.scala:126)
    ...

I suspect that the issue arises due to the large number of filter expressions I am applying on the DataFrame. The job runs fine with fewer filters, but when I increase the number, the stack overflow occurs.
Question 1. - Why StackOverflowError ?
Question 2. - Is there a more efficient way to handle a large number of filter expressions in Spark? What strategies can I use to avoid this
StackOverflowError ?
Question 3. - what is the limitation of number of filters can be applied at one time on 1 dataframe, while building execution plan?


Question 1. - Why StackOverflowError ?

Because the plan that Spark creates (using its optimizer called Catalyst) is a tree. For example, if you take
df = df.filter(
    (col("region_name") == "A") & (col("timestamp") == "2024-10-08-23-14-00")
    | (col("region_name") == "B") & (col("timestamp") == "2024-10-15-00-54-00")
    & (col("region_name") == "C") & (col("timestamp") == "2024-10-08-23-02-00")
    | (col("region_name") == "D") & (col("timestamp") == "2024-10-15-00-54-01")

And then do
df.explain(True)

you get a tree like this
(
    (
        (
            (region_name#4 = A) AND
            (timestamp#5 = 2024-10-08-23-14-00)
        ) OR 
        (
            (
                (
                    (region_name#4 = B) AND
                    (timestamp#5 = 2024-10-15-00-54-00)
                ) AND 
                (region_name#4 = C)
            ) AND
            (timestamp#5 = 2024-10-08-23-02-00)
        )
    ) OR
    (
        (region_name#4 = D) AND
        (timestamp#5 = 2024-10-15-00-54-01)
    )
)

So if you have 2000 clauses like you said, it could very well cause a stack overflow because the depth of the tree grows.

Question 2. - Is there a more efficient way to handle a large number of filter expressions in Spark? What strategies can I use to avoid this StackOverflowError ?

If you have so many conditions to apply, doing a join might be an option. Specifically a broadcast join between your table and (a much smaller) "conditions table" which gets broadcasted to the executor nodes would be more efficient.
It could look like this
data = [("emea", "2024-10-15-00-54-00", "some_data_1"),
        ("africa", "2024-10-08-23-14-00", "some_data_2"),
        ("africa", "2024-10-08-04-29-00", "some_data_3"),
        ("africa", "2024-10-13-17-14-00", "some_data_4"),
        ("apac", "2024-10-13-17-14-00", "some_data_5")]

columns = ["region_name", "timestamp", "extra_column"]

input_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

filter_data = [("emea", "2024-10-15-00-54-00"),
               ("africa", "2024-10-08-23-14-00"),
               ("africa", "2024-10-08-04-29-00")]

filter_columns = ["region_name", "timestamp"]

filter_df = spark.createDataFrame(filter_data, filter_columns)

final_filtered_df = input_df.join(
    broadcast(filter_df), 
    ["region_name", "timestamp"], 
    "inner"
)


This would work only if your conditions are in that specific format of (... & ... & ... & ...) | (... & ... & ... & ...) | (... & ... & ... & ...). Any row in the original table that matches any of the columns in the conditions table gets selected by the join.

Question 3. - what is the limitation of number of filters can be applied at one time on 1 dataframe, while building execution plan?

I am not aware of a limit, but I believe it would depend on your execution environment.
